# Number of Boys and Girls at a Party: Handshake Problem

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

I have encountered a captivating mathematical puzzle that has been testing my problem-solving skills. The puzzle revolves around the dynamic interaction of boys and girls at a party, involving handshakes and intriguing patterns. I am eager to seek insights and collaborate with fellow enthusiasts to crack this puzzle and unearth its mathematical essence.

#### Problem Description

In a party, there are both boys and girls. The following rules apply:

1. Boys are shaking hands with only girls.
2. Girls are shaking hands with both boys and other girls.

The total number of shaking hands at the party is $40$. I am trying to figure out the total number of Boys & Girls in the Party.

### Approach

Let $B$ represent the number of boys and $G$ represent the number of girls.

Each boy shakes hands with $G$ girls, contributing $B \cdot G$ handshakes.
Each girl shakes hands with $B$ boys and $G - 1$ other girls (excluding herself), contributing $B \cdot G + \frac{G \cdot (G - 1)}{2}$ handshakes among girls and boys combined.

The total number of handshakes is the sum of these contributions:
$$BG + \frac{G \cdot (G - 1)}{2}$$

Given that the total number of handshakes is $40$, we can set up the equation:
$$BG + \frac{G \cdot (G - 1)}{2} = 40$$

Simplifying the equation:
$$2BG + G^2 - G = 80$$
$$G^2 + 2BG - G = 80$$

But I can't figure out the process to figure out the integer values for $G$ and $B$ that satisfy the condition.

### Seeking Collaboration

I would greatly appreciate any collaboration or insights regarding this problem. If you have encountered similar problems or have any ideas on how to proceed, please feel free to share your thoughts.

### Expected Result

I hope to find integer values for $B$ and $G$ that satisfy the equation and represent the number of boys and girls present at the party.

*Thank you in advance for your assistance and suggestions. I look forward to any contributions that can shed light on this problem and help me arrive at a solution. Your expertise is highly valued!*

Comment: Hint: $G$ must divide 80.

Comment: If you want to try another challenging handshake puzzle, Martin Gardner published [this classic](https://mindyourdecisions.com/blog/2017/08/06/the-impossible-handshake-logic-puzzle-a-martin-gardner-classic/). The name "Lars" in it was actually the first name of its creator, who sent it to Martin Gardner. Alas I do not remember the last name. Do try to solve it yourself before reading/watching the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $G^2 + (2B-1)G - 80 = 0$ or,
$$G = \frac{-(2B-1) \pm \sqrt{(2B-1)^2 + 320}}{2}$$

Clearly the discriminant (the quantity under square root) must be perfect square. Notice the discriminant is also odd. So let
$(2B-1)^2 + 320 = (2K-1)^2$. By use of identity $x^2 - y^2 = (x+y)(x-y)$, we get
$$(K+B-1)(K-B) = 80$$
To solve this in natural numbers, observe that $K+B$ and $K-B$ have same parity. This means $K+B-1$, $K-B$ have opposite parity and we factor accordingly $$80 = 80 \times 1 = 16 \times 5$$
Since $K-B$ is smaller, we obtained two system of equations
$$K+B-1 = 80 \quad , \quad K-B = 1$$
$$K+B-1 = 16 \quad , \quad K-B = 5$$
which can be easily solved.

The solutions are $B = 6, G =5$ and $B = 40, G =1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got the same answer. But you did it more mathematically. Excellent you are!